# Can't fixed too many re render issue in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am getting too many re-render error when I am fetching data from the server and trying to show a loader when I am loading data from the server.
and error coming from this line

> 86 |  setAllVideo(res.data);

here is my code

```
const UserDetails = () => {

const classes = useStyles();
const [datas, setDatas] = useState({
name: "",
email: "",
phone: "",
userStatus: "",
});
const [imageData, setImageData] = useState({ name: "" });
const [videoData, setVideoData] = useState({ name: "" });
const [allVideo, setAllVideo] = useState([]);

const location = useLocation();
const query = new URLSearchParams(location.search);

let userId = query.get("id");
let zoneId = 1;

useEffect(() => {
async function fetchData() {
  const { data } = await axios.get(
    `http://localhost:3001/admin/api/v1/userData/${userId}`,
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `here is jwt key`,
      },
    }
  );
  setDatas(data.userData);


  const res = await axios.post(
    `http://localhost:3001/admin/api/v1/getAllVideoContent`,
    { zoneId: zoneId },
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `here is jwt key`,
      },
    }
  );

  setAllVideo(res.data);
}

fetchData();
}, [
userId,
zoneId,
datas.name,
datas.email,
datas.phone,
datas.userStatus,
videoData.name,
imageData.name,
allVideo,
]);
```

And here is the view where I use the fetch value from the API call, and it seems to be a problem when I map through the allVideo state

```
      return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={2} padding="">
      <Grid item xs={3}>
      {datas && datas.name}
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={3}>
      {datas && datas.phone}
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={3}>
      {datas && datas.email}
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={3}>
       {datas && datas.userStatus}
    </Grid>

    
    <Grid item md={6} xs={12} alignContent="center">
      {datas && datas.name}'s Currently Playing Content{" "}
    </Grid>
   
  <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
      <Modal.Title>Select a video</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
      {allVideo &&
        allVideo?.content?.map((video) => {
          return (
            <label key={video.id}>
              <input
                type="radio"
                key={video.id}
                onchange={setnewVideo(video.id)}
                value={video.id}
              />
              {"  " + video.name}
            </label>
          );
        })}
    </Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
        Close
      </Button>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
        Save Changes
      </Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
</div>
);
};
```

Comment: At first glance, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong from the `useEffect` you've shared. Are you setting state elsewhere in your code?

Answer (score 0):

In your last portion

```
}, []);
```

you should provide the dependecies. IOW which values when changed affect the useEffect. Potential candidate is userId for example. You may test it by including it as

```
}, [userId]);
```

Comment: Still getting too many re-render issues after adding [userId]);

Comment: You may show some logs or error messages. What do you mean by too many?

Comment: Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: Better paste the whole code (file).

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is a problem in dependecies.
This is your current code: `useEffect({}, []);`
But I think you need to edit like this: `useEffect({}, [userID]);`
I think, you made a wrong in using `useState({});`
Use like this : `useState();`
Hope this is helpful.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).